# Server 2019 UpdateOrchestrator - reboot missing

Tags: windows-update, windows-server-2019

We have one upgraded Server 2019 box (from Server 2016) and one new one.

On the new one I wanted to disable reboot (and rename the file and use a blank directory instead) to prevent this really annoying default habit of the server deciding to reboot without notice during the night.

This is what the upgrade looks like

[image: server 2019 upgraded from 2016]

and this is what a fresh install looks like

[image: Server 2019 Fresh Install]

Am I missing something, or are some of these annoying scheduled tasks added later, or had MS actually listened and removed this as the default now?

Thanks

Comment: It would be entirely unsurprising if Microsoft had removed the dependency on the scheduled task, precisely because people kept breaking the intended functionality by disabling it - but that's pure speculation on my part.  If you are concerned that these servers might reboot, the other solution is to use Group Policy or the equivalent registry keys to configure Windows Update to only install updates on request.  (You still have to make sure to only install updates at times when you can reboot afterwards.)

Comment: Reboot appeared 24 hours later after some updates. The only way I could disable it was to download the PSExcec utility. MS are getting more and more annoying! If I run SConfig both these boxes are set to 'DownloadOnly' but I have noticed they are both installing anti-virus updates themselves - not a good sign!

Comment: The anti-virus updates are automatically installed by the anti-virus software, so that doesn't necessarily indicate that the "download only" setting isn't working.

Comment: Not on all the other 2016 boxes it doesn't - my morning routine (between espressos) is checking updates and installing the anti-virus ones. Updates generally used to be straightforward with 2008 R2 (and even 2012) but 2016 has caused so many problems I have to be sure there is a backup before installing updates

Comment: I suspect that if you check on a Monday you'll find that the definition versions aren't the same ones you installed the previous Friday.  But the behaviour may have changed, it isn't something I've been paying close attention to and my servers are all on WSUS anyway.

Comment: Not sure I understand that. The KB is always the same number, the definitions increase by some random value each time. With Win 10 workstations it installs the virus definitions and the patch Tuesday updates but doesn't reboot. I don't want that to happen with servers. Was a little wary of WSUS when I read that upgrades can leave the box unusable - format and start again unusable.